# How to limit a column that just accepts specific values?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column named `vote_value`. Always the content of this column is `1` or `-1`. Now for more security I want to limit it that just accepts two value *(1 or -1)*. there is any solution ?

I can do that via PHP before inserting:

```
if($vote_value !== '1' && $vote_value !== '-1'){ echo 'not valid!' }
```

But I want to know that is it possible via mysql ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have options other than a `check` constraint (which MySQL's storage engines do not implement, although the syntax is accepted) or a trigger.

One is to use an enumerated type.  This validates on input.  However, I'm not a fan of enumerated types in general, and they get confusing for numeric data.

Another way is a foreign key relationship:

```
create table refValidVotes (
    vote int,
    description varchar(255)
);

insert into refValidVotes(Vote, Description)
    select 1, 'Aye' union all select -1, 'Nay';

create table . . . (
    . . .
    vote int not null,  -- Perhaps you want to allow NULL
    constraint chk_valid_vote foreign key (vote) references refValidVotes(vote)
);
```

And one other option is to use `bit`, if you really only have two values:

```
vote bit(1)
```

However, the two values are 0 and 1, not -1 and 1.

Comment: Please add a point to your answer and noting that `bit` support was limited to MyISAM and this was extended to InnoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you would use a check constraint for that but MySQL currently does not support that. Use a trigger instead that cancels the update/insert if the value is not correct

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER check_value_trigger
BEFORE UPDATE ON your_table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.vote_value not in (1,-1)) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'value out of range';
   END IF;    
END
$$
```

You need 2 triggers - one for updates and one for inserts.

Comment: thanks, just what is `$$` ? it is the same with `//` ?

Comment: It is a alternative delimter for the trigger definition. If you don't define it the definition would end at the first `;` and would make it incomplete

Comment: I see, but one think, my table has two trigger for updating `total_votes` in `posts` tables (after insert, after update). Now I want to know, If I create two trigger (as you said: before insert, before update) for checking, then 4 trigger for one table is normal thing ?

Comment: @Sajad, there is no other way than handling this with a trigger. I would suggest you do this validation from your application end rather in DB end.

Comment: Personally I would not recommend using many triggers. It can make it hard sometimes to find errors or mysterious behaviour. I would only use it if really necessary. If you can check the correct input in your logic, that might be enough. And as gordon just posted - you better just use a `bit` instead

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use *(echo)* trigger error via php ? `SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'value out of range';`